# QAF-Cucumber 3.1.0 is not working with Cucumber 6

Tags: qaf

getting following exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/gherkin/Location

implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '6.11.0'
implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '6.11.0'

Answer (score 0):

QAF-cucumber 3.1.0 supports cucumber-5. You can try using cucumber 5.